# Change grunt serve default path

Tags: gruntjs

I use grunt-serve and access the files that it serves through 
localhost:9000, I want to change that to

```
localhost:9000/mypath
```

I read on the documentation that I can do the following

```
'serve': {
    'path': '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/project'
}
```

But I don't know where to put this options.

I have found a similar question but no answers.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration block for the grunt-serve plugin should reside (as with any other task configuration) in the config object passed to [`grunt.config.init`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.init), e.g.:

```js
grunt.config.init({
    serve: {
        path: '/Users/user/Documents/workspace/project'
    },
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I put this one 
   serve: {
          path: 'apps'
      },
inside grunt.initConfig then I run grunt serve but I am still getting the content of the root folder of my application.

Comment: @user3814030 - please post more info, e.g. your gruntfile.js

Comment: Please close your question - it is a dupe of your other one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30599385/grunt-serve-change-default-path