# grunt-serve change default path

Tags: gruntjs

I am using grunt-serve and trying to change the default path, 
in my initConfig I use the following

```
serve: {
    path: '/mypath'
},
```

Then when I visit localhost:9000 I still seeing the files and folders of the gruntfile.js root folder.
I want to change the root path to /mypath and make all links relative to that. Also when I visit folder that has an index.html file I want the server to display it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change grunt serve default path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595778/change-grunt-serve-default-path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `options.serve.path`, not `path`

```
grunt.initConfig({
    serve: {
        options: {
            serve: {
                path: '/mypath'
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: this is kind of ridiculous. Especially if you consider the port needs to be on the `options` node, not the `serve` node. Why there's a redundantly named inner node, who knows.